# validations with "setCustomValidity" incompatible with alerts

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Im working with forms so need to customize validations with "setCustomValidity" function, the problem comes when i work with alerts and validations in the same.

The button that i use to send my data form got type="submit" when i use that kind my form is making validations correctly but that type makes a refresh so the alert never shows up.
If i switch the type to type="button" then makes the opposite. Validations are not working and alerts finally shows up.

Here is some of the form´s side code:

```
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="col-12 user-img">
            <img src="../../images/nuevoConcesionario.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <span id="switching1" class="d-none">   
            <center>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="mensajeError" value="AA">
                </div>
            </center>
        </span>
        <form class="formu">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="nombre" class="col-form-label">Nombre Concesionario(*)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomConcesionario" placeholder="Nombre Concesionario" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="Nif" class="col-form-label">NIF(*)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nifConcesionario" placeholder="Ejemplo NIF: A58818501" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6" >
                    <label for="ciudad" class="col-form-label">Ciudad(*)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomCiudad" placeholder="Ciudad" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="cp" class="col-form-label">Codigo Postal</label>
                    <input type="text" id="cpConcesionario" placeholder="Codigo Postal" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6" >
                    <label for="ciudad" class="col-form-label">Telefono Contacto</label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tlf" placeholder="Telefono Contacto">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="nom_admin" class="col-form-label">Nombre Administrador(*)</label>
                        <input type="text" id="nomAdministrador" placeholder="Nombre Administrador" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label for="email" class="col-form-label">Email(*)</label>
                    <input type="email" id="emailConcesionario" placeholder="email" class="form-control" required>
                </div>              
            </div>                  

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label for="nom_admin" class="col-form-label">Dirección(*)</label>
                    <input type="text" id="direccion" placeholder="direccion" class="form-control" required>
                </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 25% 0 25%">
                    <button  type="button" id="bEnviar" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="altaConcesionario();">Dar de alta concesionario</button> 
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
```

Here is altaConcesionario validation´s function:

```
function altaConcesionario() {
var nomConcesionario = document.getElementById('nomConcesionario');
var nifConcesionario = document.getElementById('nifConcesionario');
var nomCiudad = document.getElementById('nomCiudad');
var nomAdministrador = document.getElementById('nomAdministrador');
var cpConcesionario = document.getElementById('cpConcesionario');
var telefono = document.getElementById('tlf');
var direccion = document.getElementById('direccion');
var emailConcesionario = document.getElementById('emailConcesionario');

// TODO unificar este mismo patron
var nomConcesionarioPatt = /[A-Za-z0-9]{4,60}/;
var nomCiudadPatt = /[A-Za-z0-9]{4,60}/;
var nomAdminPatt = /[A-Za-z0-9]{4,60}/;
var addrPatt = /[A-Za-z0-9]{4,60}/;
var emailConcesionarioPatt = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;

var elNif = checkNif(nifConcesionario.value);

var validate = true;

// Nombre concesionario
if (nomConcesionario.value) {
    nomConcesionario.setCustomValidity("");
    if (!nomConcesionarioPatt.test(nomConcesionario.value)) {
        mostrarAlertaValidacion("Error en el ingreso. min[4] caracteres");
        nomConcesionario.setCustomValidity("Error en el ingreso. min[4] caracteres");
        validate = false;
    }

} else {
    nomConcesionario.setCustomValidity("Por favor, rellene campo 'nombre concesionario'");
    mostrarAlertaValidacion("Por favor, rellene campo 'nombre concesionario'");

    validate = false;
}

// Nif concesionario
if (nifConcesionario.value) {

    nifConcesionario.setCustomValidity("");

    if (!elNif) {
        nifConcesionario
                .setCustomValidity("El nif introducido no es correcto");
        validate = false;
    }
} else {
    nifConcesionario
            .setCustomValidity("Por favor, rellene campo 'NIF concesionario'");
    validate = false;
}

// Nombre ciudad
if (nomCiudad.value) {

    nomCiudad.setCustomValidity("");
    if (!nomCiudadPatt.test(nomCiudad.value)) {
        nomCiudad
                .setCustomValidity("Error en el ingreso. min[4] caracteres");
        validate = false;
    }

} else {
    nomCiudad.setCustomValidity("Por favor, rellene campo 'nombre ciudad'");
    validate = false;
}

// Nombre administrador
if (nomAdministrador.value) {
    nomAdministrador.setCustomValidity("");
    if (!nomAdminPatt.test(nomAdministrador.value)) {
        nomAdministrador
                .setCustomValidity("Error en el ingreso. min[4] caracteres");
        validate = false;
    }

} else {
    nomAdministrador
            .setCustomValidity("Por favor, rellene campo 'nombre administrador'");
    validate = false;
}

if (direccion.value) {
    direccion.setCustomValidity("");
    if (!addrPatt.test(direccion.value)) {
        direccion
                .setCustomValidity("Error en el ingreso. min[4] caracteres");
        validate = false;
    }

} else {
    direccion.setCustomValidity("Por favor, rellene campo 'direccion'");
    validate = false;
}

// Email concesionario
if (emailConcesionario.value) {
    emailConcesionario.setCustomValidity("");
    if (!emailConcesionarioPatt.test(emailConcesionario.value)) {

        emailConcesionario
                .setCustomValidity("El email introducido no es correcto. mail@dominio.com");
        validate = false;
    }

} else {
    emailConcesionario
            .setCustomValidity("Por favor, rellene campo 'email colaborador'");
    validate = false;
}

// TODO falta validacion email
// TODO poner las rewdirecciones en su sitio
// Si estan todos los campos rellenos entra
if (validate) {
    // POPUP
    // SI TRUE
    $
            .ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : '/proyecto/Api',
                data : {
                    action : 'addConcesionario',
                    auth_token : auth_token,
                    usuario_sesion : usuario,
                    nomConcesionario : nomConcesionario.value,
                    nifConcesionario : nifConcesionario.value,
                    nomCiudad : nomCiudad.value,
                    nomAdministrador : nomAdministrador.value,
                    cpConcesionario : cpConcesionario.value,
                    telefono : telefono.value,
                    direccion : direccion.value,
                    email : emailConcesionario.value
                },
                success : function(response) {
                    alert("EXITO");
                    window.location.href = "/proyecto/administracion/administracion.jsp";

                },
                error : function(result) {
                    alert("ERROR");
                    window.location.href = "/proyecto/administracion/administracion.jsp";
                }

            });

}
```

so i would like to know if there is any reasonable way to make both works together as i need to give information to the final user and is really important for me both of functions.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you need to prevent form submitting [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). Take a look at example below

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#myForm');
form.addEventListener('submit', ev => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  //Your code here (validation, http etc)
  console.log('Prevented');
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="nombre" class="col-form-label">Nombre Concesionario(*)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomConcesionario" placeholder="Nombre Concesionario" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="Nif" class="col-form-label">NIF(*)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nifConcesionario" placeholder="Ejemplo NIF: A58818501" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="ciudad" class="col-form-label">Ciudad(*)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomCiudad" placeholder="Ciudad" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="cp" class="col-form-label">Codigo Postal</label>
            <input type="text" id="cpConcesionario" placeholder="Codigo Postal" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="ciudad" class="col-form-label">Telefono Contacto</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tlf" placeholder="Telefono Contacto">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="nom_admin" class="col-form-label">Nombre Administrador(*)</label>
            <input type="text" id="nomAdministrador" placeholder="Nombre Administrador" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="email" class="col-form-label">Email(*)</label>
            <input type="email" id="emailConcesionario" placeholder="email" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="nom_admin" class="col-form-label">Dirección(*)</label>
            <input type="text" id="direccion" placeholder="direccion" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 25% 0 25%">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Dar de alta concesionario</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```